# API for incident management

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

We use alert policies in order to monitor issues with some of our services. For a small subset of our alert policies, we'd like to react in an automated way to incidents raised by one of our alert policies. For this purpose, we created a pub/sub notifaction channel, topic and push subscription which sends alert notifications to a cloud run service. The cloud run service helps us with reducing manual opertations effort. For some reason, we'd like the cloud run service to also acknowledge, mute and close incidents by using an API.

While I found public APIs for [managing alert policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies) and [notification channels](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.notificationChannels), I cannot find an API for managing incidents. Is there a public one?

Comment: Are you talking about error reporting service?

Comment: We have some alerts defined that monitor i.e. CPU usage. In case of CPU usage exceeding or falling below some threshold, we take some automated scaling measures that go beyond cloud run's auto scaling capabilities. In this case, we want to mute the incident that has been opened by the alert policy. Only I cannot find a public API that allows me to do so - the GCP console let's you do this.